# How to set default form fields value from controller

Tags: 8

How to setup default form fields value from a form created in a controller?

I tryed to set the $form_state param but it does not work.

```
...
$form_state = new FormState();
$form_state->set('myfield_1', 'car');
$form_state->set('myfield_2', 'bus');
$form = $this->formBuilder->buildForm('Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyForm', $form_state);
return $form;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the default values to getForm():

```
return $this->formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyForm', $default1, $default2);
```

And set the default values in the form class:

```
class MyForm extends FormBase {

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $default1 = NULL, $default2 = NULL) {

    $form['field1'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Field 1'),
      '#default_value' => $default1,
    ];

    // ...

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The working example for add node form:

```
       <?php

        namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

        use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

        class addController extends ControllerBase {

           public function build() {

             $entity = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->create(array(
               'type' => 'SomeContentType',
             ));

             $entity->set('field_link_to_item', 5);

             $form = $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($entity);

             return $form;
           }

        }
```